# Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module '@custom-path'

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use Path Mapping for Cloud Functions but when I use a custom path like `import * as b from '@custom-path/barrel'` I get an error on tslint for implicit imports. If I disable this rule and try to deploy, I get the following error:
`Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module '@custom-path'`

```
 "baseUrl": "../",
    "paths": {
      "@be-utils/*": ["functions/src/utils/*"],
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong?
If not, how can I use path mapping with Cloud Functions?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: No I didn't. My best bet is using the tsconfig file in a higher level and using that one to deploy, but didn't try yet.

Comment: Any solution in 2021?