# How to use TS Path Mapping with Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

How do I use TS Path Mapping with Firebase Cloud Functions?
I tried without success:

```
"baseUrl": ".",
  "paths": {
    "@custom-path/*": ["src/utils/*"],
    "@other-path/*": ["../other/path/*"]
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried to follow these instructions https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript ?

Comment: Hi, Gonçalo. Thanks for the response. I know how to use typescript, what I don't know is how to setup the path mapping. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50785855/error-parsing-triggers-cannot-find-module-custom-path Here's the full description

Comment: Am curious about how to do this as well

Comment: @william Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No solutions yet, I'll get back to it in a week or so to try again, but I'm having no luck

Answer (score 15):

It's `2024` and the neatest way to do this is to use [tsc-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc-alias).

On `tsconfig.json`, add `baseUrl` and add your `paths` under `compilerOptions`. Something like:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@constants/*": ["api/constants/*"],
      "@interfaces/*": ["api/interfaces/*"],
      "@middlewares/*": ["api/middlewares/*"],
      "@modules/*": ["api/modules/*"],
      "@services/*": ["api/services/*"]
    },
    ...
}
```

Then, change your `serve` and `build` scripts, under `package.json`. Like:

```json
...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc && tsc-alias",
    "build:watch": "concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"tsc-alias -w\"",
    "serve": "concurrently --kill-others \"firebase emulators:start --only functions\" \"npm run build:watch\"",
    ...
  },
...
```

☝️ here I'm using `concurrently`, but feel free to use whatever you like.

And that's it. You can now import stuff using your defined paths, like:

```
import { messages } from '@constants/responses'
import CandidatesService from '@modules/candidates/candidates.service'
import { IModule } from '@interfaces/module.interface'
```

etc...

Comment: Didn't work for me, because there were circular dependencies in the project. Here's a command to detect them: `npx dpdm --help`. This is the package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dpdm

Answer (score 12):

Finally I was able to do this with `module-alias` NPM package.

1. Install it as non-dev dependency: `yarn add module-alias @types/module-alias`
2. Create a file `fixTsPaths.ts` or whatever with content like this:

```js
import * as ModuleAlias from 'module-alias';

ModuleAlias.addAliases({
    'common': __dirname + '/../../../common',
});
```

Here's the trick about the path `/../../../common`: in my case this folder is outside `functions`, and Typescript replicates folders structure during the build, so that's could be the reason why https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths was not working out of the box. So in every case one needs to check this path and find appropriate '..' count :)

3. And finally import this file in your `index.ts` at the very top:

```js
import './fixTsPaths';
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: you can generate that mapping from tsconfig.json, no?

Comment: simple case of generating aliases:
```ts
import tsconfig from '../tsconfig.json';
import ModuleAlias from 'module-alias';
import path from 'path';

const { compilerOptions: { baseUrl } } = tsconfig;

const aliases = Object.entries(tsconfig.compilerOptions.paths).reduce((acc, [key, [alias]]) => ({
  ...acc,
  [key.replace('/*', '')]: path.join('../', baseUrl, alias).replace('/*', '/'),
}), {});

ModuleAlias.addAliases(aliases);
```

Comment: @BennyPowers that's simple? I don't want to see complex then /s

Comment: i regret using the word "simple". What I should have written was "Here is a possible implementation which reads the aliases in tsconfig and applies them to ModuleAlias"

Thank you @Spock for calling me out on my use of loaded language.

Comment: @Benny Powers just kidding dude ;) .. I just felt like an idiot hehe

Comment: I appreciate that your comment was light-hearted, but I still think it was unprofessional of me to use that kind of minimizing language for something which is in fact quite involved, so thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the rule `no-implicit-dependencies: true` on the `tslint.json`. You can pass additional params to whitelist your custom paths:

```
"no-implicit-dependencies": [true, ["@custom-path", "@other-path"]],
```

Comment: Even if you suppress the tslint, the actual transpiled JS tries to import third party modules named `@whatever-path`. I switched back to relative import.

Answer (score 2):

for anyone who still struggles with this issue, but the below code at the top of the entry point file (main.ts).
don't forget to adjust the tsconfig.json file path if it is not in the default location

```js
const tsConfig = require('../tsconfig.json');
const tsConfigPaths = require('tsconfig-paths');
tsConfigPaths.register({
    baseUrl: __dirname,
    paths: tsConfig.compilerOptions.paths,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with [@zerollup/ts-transform-paths](https://github.com/zerkalica/zerollup/tree/5aee60287647350215c81d0b2da5a30717d9dccb/packages/ts-transform-paths) NPM package.

1. Install @zerollup/ts-transform-paths as dev dependency: `yarn add -D @zerollup/ts-transform-paths`
2. Setup following config of webpack + ts-loader.

```
const tsTransformPaths = require('@zerollup/ts-transform-paths');

module.exports = {
  ... // other config
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        options: {
          getCustomTransformers: (program) => {
            const transformer = tsTransformPaths(program);

            return {
              before: [transformer.before], // for updating paths in generated code
              afterDeclarations: [transformer.afterDeclarations] // for updating paths in declaration files
            };
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

See more in detail: https://github.com/zerkalica/zerollup/tree/5aee60287647350215c81d0b2da5a30717d9dccb/packages/ts-transform-paths